# My code from sql query does not work when I do it in visual studio

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I have this query in my sql management studio:

```
select Hotel.Name,count(Arrangement.ArrangementID) as NumberOfArrangements
from Hotel,Arrangement
where DepartureDate >='2020-04-16 00:00:00.000'
    and ReturnDate <='2020-04-26 00:00:00.000'
    and Hotel.Country ='England'
    and Hotel.Category ='4 stars'
group by Hotel.Name
```

and it shows me what I need which is the name of the hotel and how many arrangements do I have for the particular hotel that fits the requirements.
But when I try to do that in Visual Studio it shows me a blank table
The code that I'm using in VS:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"connection string that I copied from the Project>Add new Data 
Source window");
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            string k1 = "select Hotel.Name,count(Arrangement.ArrangementID) as NumberOfArrangements 
            from Hotel,Arrangement where DepartureDate >='" + monthCalendar1.SelectionStart + "' and 
            ReturnDate <='" + monthCalendar2.SelectionStart + "' and Hotel.Country='" + 
            comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and Hotel.Category='" + 
            comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' group by Hotel.Name";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(k1, con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            ad.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            MessageBox.Show("Success");
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Close();
        }
   }
```

The whole string k1 is in one line it just doesn't fit that well here.And I binded the comboboxes 
like this:
[Bind for the Category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgjfN.png)

[Bind for the Country](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BI5dU.png)

So I don't understand why it doesn't work, I tried everything that I could think of and still can't get it right.I know this is probably realy hard to read and understand but please bear with me this is my first question.
Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: debug and get the contents of k1. Run that in SSMS

Comment: What Ghost said makes sense, for debugging, without more details my guess would be that the startStart values are not in the format your db expects.

Comment: Debug `k1` value and copy to SQL Management Studio and check how it look and the result